# facebook page tab not available over ssl

Tags: facebook

So I created a facebook app using iframes, I'm using it as a tab on a facebook page and it works.

But if I use HTTPS, the tab isnt even there.

Anyone know how to fix this?

thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook recently enabled the ability for users to set their accounts to use secure browsing (https / ssl). In your application settings > Facebook integration section you now have 2 fields: Secure Canvas URL & Secure Tab URL which in order for your app to work if a user has enable secure browsing, you will need to fill those in. This also requires that the server you are hosting your app on has a valid and configured SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are browsing over HTTPS (which is a something a user can now enable in their FB account settings), then the iframe will need to be pulled in over a secure connection too.

This is a known issue (marked as fixed and resolved - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15200) and, rather than attempting to simply call the same URL over HTTPS, Facebook now provide a separate field under the integration settings for the URL of a secure version of the iframe. If this does not exist, then the tab will not display over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Sergiogx, make sure you filled both fields Canvas Tab URL and Secure Canvas Tab URL. I'm using free facebook page hosting from http://hostfb.com and they also provide SSL support.